# Is it worth it to continue supporting iOS 4.x when iOS 6 is released?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on a major feature update for my application and would love to include features such as iCloud, Core Data, ARC and storyboards among other things.  **The issue is that I don't have data on how many users are still running 4.x.**  I realize that the ideal solution would be to support both at once and just select the available features based on what version the particular device was on, but my upgrades would be so substantial that this would be very difficult.  **Does anyone else have reliable data on the percentage of users on older versions? And also would it be advisable to release an iOS 5+ version of my app separately as an "App 2.0?"**

Comment: Its quite common for developers to support (in some fashion) the latest and one l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an article for reference.

[80% on iOS5](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-57450474-37/apple-365-million-ios-devices-sold-80-percent-running-ios-5/)

With the OTA updates, Apple devices are normally upgraded very quickly.  The decision to create an iOS5 only app early this year was not too hard to make and more so now.

Comment: Thanks for that, I can't believe I missed that link in my research.

Answer (score 4):

... my company`s app still suport ios 3.x ,although only 2% on ios 3.x and below... but we can do the vast majority of ios4.0+ effect with 3.x and below API.

Comment: we do a lot of high profile apps, we draw the line at 4.1.  Note: if it is a computationally intense app, we set the lower limit at 4.3 (as this prevents the iphone 3g from installing)

Answer (score 2):

I believe iOS users are the fastest ones to upgrade when there's a new update. Also I don't know if it is accepted to have 2 different apps for different versions of iOS. What you could do is having the app check what version of iOS the app is running and exclude the features that are unsupported for lower versions.

Can't find any really reliable sources but you could check out some update stats around.

[Link](http://www.gsmarena.com/developer_stats_show_quick_adoption_of_ios_51_by_users-news-4014.php)

Answer (score 0):

**Changes for ios 6 and Xcode 4.5.x**

1. Xcode 4.5.x (and later) does **not** support generating armv6 binaries.
2. Now includes **iPhone 5/armv7s** support.
3. The minimum supported deployment target with Xcode 4.5.x or later is **iOS 4.3**.
4. The minimum support for iPhone is **iPhone 3GS** or later as earlier versions use armv6.