# iphone/ipad development moving forward

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm about to develop my first iOS application and as far as OS support goes, should I be building against iOS 6 or iOS 5?  What's the typical industry practice when a new iOS is about to be released?  Also, how is the backwards compatibility?  By that I mean, if I were to build for 5, will users running 6 also be able to install and run it when they download it from the App Store?  Also, what are the typical statistics of upgrade v.s. not upgrade when it comes to new iOS releases for iPhone and iPad users.  Any blogs/references or personal experiences regarding this topic would be great!

Comment: As dude said below go with the latest...if its your first iOS app, you dont have the experience to deal with backward compatibility issues in your shiny new app anyway.  It can be tricky.  Get your stuff out there on the latest and greatest and worry about that stuff later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably quickly develop using the iOS6 **SDK**.

But **using the iOS6 SDK don't mean that your app will only be compatible with iOS6**. It only means that you will be able to use all methods that exists in iOS6, including methods that already existed in previous APIs (in iOS5 for example), **and** new APIs introduced in iOS6.

So even if you use the iOS6 SDK, your application will be compatible with iOS5 and iOS6 as long as you use methods that were already present in iOS5 (the majority of them).

- If you use methods that were already present in iOS5 and are still present in iOS6 (that is the majority of the methods of the SDK), your application will work in both iOS5 and iOS6. But you won't take advantage of the new stuff introduced in iOS6 that were not present in iOS5, as iOS5 users won't have these features in their OS.
- You can use new methods introduced in iOS6 and that were not present in iOS5, but then either you drop the iOS5 support, or you have to make sure to check the method availability before using it. For example, if you intend to have a button that makes use of some classes or methods that only have been introduced in iOS6 and were not present in iOS5, check the availability of the class or method first, and only call it if it is available. And you may inform the user that this feature is unavailable for him if the class/method is not available in his version of the OS, encouraging him to upgrade its OS version.

For more info, **I strongly recommend you read the [SDK Compatibility Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html) from Apple documentation**, that explains it all: the difference between the version of the SDK and the version of the OS you support, how to make checks to see if a method newly introduced in the latest SDK can be used (namely prevent to use an method that was inexistant in iOS5 if the user is running iOS5), and so on.

Answer (score 2):

What is your timeframe for delivering this app?  Unless there are specific features of iOS 6 you want to take advantage of, it is probably better in the near term to target iOS 6 but guard against using iOS 6 features.  This will then be able to be installed and run on the majority of devices.

If you build for 5, it should still be able to run on iOS 6 as well.

Upgrades are fairly fast for iOS.  See my answer in this question:

[Is it worth it to continue supporting iOS 4.x when iOS 6 is released?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679412/is-it-worth-it-to-continue-supporting-ios-4-x-when-ios-6-is-released/11679604#11679604)